# how to replace some chars in the string with other chars by the user?

Tags: java

I wrote a text, and i want to change some chars to any other chars which the user will choosing them, I tried and couldn't find the correct answer, so please guide me.
the code in the MyTest Class is:

```
public String replace(String input,char from,char to){
   String input2 ="";
   String input3="";
   this.input=input3;
   for(int i=0;i<input.length();i++){
       for(int j=0;j<input3.length();j++){
          if(input.charAt(i)==input3.charAt(j)){
              input2=input3.replace(from, to);
              System.out.println(input2);
          }
       }

   }
   return input2;
}
```

And the code in the Main Class:

```
System.out.println("please enter the new character: ");
   char c1 = scan.next().charAt(0);
   System.out.println("Please choose the letters that you want to change it which in the text:");
   String ltr = scan.next();
   obj1.convertChars(ltr, c1);
```

Comment: You cannot "repalace" chars in a string, not easily anyway because Strings are immutable. You can however createa new string object with the replaced chars

Comment: Also: Why did it fail? Give us an example and explain what did you insert, what did you get and what did you expect.

Comment: where is `convertChars` defined? from where **your** `replace` method is called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question seemed a bit unclear. I hope you want a function like this:
Call this function from the main function. Pass the string "abcde", 'a', 'x'. It will return you "xbcde".

```
public String replace(String inputStr, char from, char to){
    StringBuffer newString=new StringBuffer();
    for(int i=0;i<inputStr.length();i++){
        if(inputStr.charAt(i)==from){
            newString.append(to);
        }
        else{
            newString.append(inputStr.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    return newString.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**(1) What you should do:**

There is a simple method for what you are after: [`String#replace(char,char)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29):

```
String replaced = myString.replace(from,to);
```

**(2) Why your code fails:**

Note you are iterating and trying to invoke `replace()` on `input3`, while it is an empty string! you never changed it! effectively your method do nothing (except assigning the instance variable `input`. Definetly not what you wanted.

**(3) Also important:** `String`s in java are *immutable*

In java, `String` is immutable - so what you are doing is actually crating a new string with replaced characters, and NOT replacing the characters in the same string object!

Changing the `String` is not as simple, and should be avoided, but can be done using the [reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do shouldn't even be a method. Here's why:

```
public String replace(String input,char from,char to){
    return input.replace(from, to);
}
```

Thus kind of method adds no value - you should just call the [`replace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29) method of String directly.